# Android: modify a textview from a Service

Tags: android, android-service

in my project I've a class that extends VpnService class. Since I can't call findViewById() method, how can I modify a textview in my layout from this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You somehow tell the activity, if it is still around, to update the `TextView`. Possible means for this include:

- Using `LocalBroadcastManager`
- Using an event bus like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)
- Using a `Messenger` tied to a `Handler`
- Etc.

Note that usually there is no guarantee that this activity exists, unless the service is only running while the activity is in the foreground.

Comment: thanks, I've done it this way: 
-in the service class i put
     Intent intent = new Intent("NetStat");
     intent.putExtra("NetStat", netstat);
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

and into my activity I registered a receiver that waits my broadcast message. Inside the code of the receiver I can modify my editText.

Thank you for the suggestion!